# how to find the list activities delivered to integration stream on a particular day?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearcase-ucm, clearcase-automation

We use to take nightly builds irrespective of any files were delivered to integration stream or not. What i would like to do is , find the list of deliveries done on a particular day.

If there were no deliveries to integration stream then build will not be triggered.

Through project explorer itself we can see. but i would like to know from commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any deliver in UCM will generate an activity call `deliver.xxx`.

Simply list all activities for a given Stream (see [cleartool lsact man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsactivity.htm))

```
–in stream-selector [ –r/ecurse ]
```

> Displays a list of all activities in the specified stream.
>   With `–r/ecurse`, includes activities in child streams.

So:

```
cleartool lsact -in stream:aStream@\aPVob -fmt "%n %d\n"|grep deliver
```

And filter through the dates (`%d`) in order to get only the deliver activities for that day.

(`stream:aStream@\aPVob` is a "stream selector", although you can directly use `aStream@\aPVob` in this case: `cleartool` is expecting a stream name parameter after the `-in` option)

Comment: I think there is no option called -stream it seems. Equvalent and corrected in DOS prompt. "cleartool lsact -in Components_Integration@\My_PVOB -fmt "%n %d\n"| find "deliver" .Please update your answer , i will accept it

Comment: @Samselvaprabu: I have fixed the `lsstream -in` syntax and added some references.