# How to obsolete all the delivery tasks?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearcase-ucm

In our project every day there will be lot of deliveries to integration stream.

When i am looking at my integration stream through project explorer UI, It has plenty of delivery-XX activities?

Can i obsolete them? Is it recommended? How to obsolete all the delivery activity in integration stream using cleartool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cleartool lock -obsolete activity:deliver-xx@\myPVob
```

is enough to obsolete one activity.

You could list all activities in a Stream, and parse the result in order to prepare the right list of commands.

```
cleartool lsact -in stream:aStream@\aPVob
```

Comment: Last command is also illustrated in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731616/how-to-find-the-list-activities-delivered-to-integration-stream-on-a-particular/8732330#8732330

Comment: Is it possible to do wildcard in activity name like "cleartool lock -obsolete activity:deliver*@\myPVob". So that it will automatically obsolete all.

Comment: @Samselvaprabu: I don't think so. I never saw wildcard working for those commands. I just tested it and it keep returning "Error: No match for wildcard" even in an interactive cleartool shell.