# How to get latest UCM activity number for a Clear Case Integration stream using command line

Tags: clearcase-ucm

Is there a command in CC to get the latest UCM activity ID through which files were delivered to Integration stream from Developer stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly, but using [`cleartool lsactivity`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsactivity.htm), you can list all activities of a given stream, and grep the ones with "`deliver.`" in it, keeping the last one (the most recent one).

See more at "[how to find the list activities delivered to integration stream on a particular day?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8732330/6309)": the command would be like:

```
cleartool lsact -in stream:aStream@\aPVob -fmt "%n\n"|grep deliver|tail
```

Comment: Replace `aStream` by the integration stream name, and "`aPVob`" by the pvob of said stream.