# How to find list of changes delivered since yesterday from delivered activities?

Tags: clearcase-ucm, cleartool

I am using  cleartool find command to find the list of files delivered to integration stream since previous day. Following is the command [ I am storing the result in powershell variable]

```
        $ListOfFilesChanges = cleartool find "$folderPath" -version "{brtype($streamName) && created_since($fromDate)}" -print
```

But it is taking much time as we are verifying many folder. If we are able to find list of activities delivered since yesterday and find the list of files delivered as part of delivery it may be faster.

I need to find the list of deliveries done previous day. Then need to check what are all the files delivered as part of it.

Is there any cleartool command available to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Deliver in UCM generates a deliver activity, named "`deliver.dev_stream.xxxx`" (see an example in "[Describe baseline and expand deliver and rebase activities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9328314/6309)").
You can use [`fmt_ccase` filters](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) to display the date:

```
cleartool lsact -in yourIntStream@\yourPVob -fmt "%Nd\t%n\n" | sort -r
```

This is similar to a previous question "[how to find the list activities delivered to integration stream on a particular day?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8732330/6309)".

It would be easier to list all activities created since yesterday, and, for each delivery activity, list their versions in the change set of said activities.

You can describe each version found in those activities with the `-fmt "%En"` parameter to get the element name (that is the name of the file instead of the extended pathname of the version), and sort that list to get rid of similar elements (`|uniq`)